# Getting error on boxplot with column input

Tags: python, dataframe, boxplot

I have a dataframe which contains three columns - id, thermal template, and lighting density value. Here is an example of the data -
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lfpX.png)

**I want to create** a horizontal boxplot that groups by thermal_template, similar to this -
[desired boxplot layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGmlt.png) except on the y-axis it would be the various thermal_templates and on the x-axis it would be lighting_density. I am using this code:

`boxplot = result.boxplot(column='thermal_template', figsize=(18,8), rot = 90)`

and **I am getting an error** -
KeyError: "None of [Index(['thermal_template'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

I have confirmed that 'thermal_template' is a column label.

Code for reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'ID': [1, 2, 3], 'thermal_template': ['Zone A', 'Zone A/B', 'Zone A/B'], 'lighting_density':[0.36, 0.88, 0.74 ]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

boxplot = df.boxplot(column='thermal_template')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying both `by` and `column` produces the desired output with your example data:

`df.boxplot(by='thermal_template', column='lighting_density')`

[image]